# How to mock the value of a parameter in a service class

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

How can I test the following service method with Junit test? It's a very simple rebuild of my code and only an example.
I want to test in a JUnit test, what's happening, if the **file string is empty or null**.
Unfortunately I'm new to testing with JUnit. I read already some examples for rest controller and services and repos to me mocked and the methods for it, but here I have no idea how it could work. May someone can help?

```
public class MyService {

    private String fileName = "src/main/resources";
 // or
 // private String fileName = ${modulename.config.filename};
//  @Autowired
//  private RepoService RepoService;

    @EventListener
    public void init(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        try {
        myMethod();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // LOGGING
        };
}


public void myMethod() {

        if(fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
            // doSomething with file and IOException
            // save in repo
        } else {
            // LOGGING
        }       
    }
}


    public void myMethod() {        
        if(fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
            // doSomething with IOException
        } else {
            // LOGGING
        }       
    }
}
```

The test should look like the following. I tried to set the value somehow in the test, but it does not make sense and it's not set then.

```
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void fileNameTest() {
        // GIVEN
        //Mockito.when()

        // WHEN

        // THEN
    }

}
```

Comment: why would you test `fileName` when filename is hardcoded? Are you ever changing fileName during lifecycle of `MyService` instance?

Comment: Actually I would put the filepath and name in application.properties.I want to test it, so that in case the file location has moved for example, that it works either.

Answer (score 1):

To change the value of a private variable Use `Field` modification using `Reflection` API.
[Here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-access-private-field-and-method.html)'s a nice explanation on how to do this.